# Combining -= and += modifiers in buildout scripts

Tags: python, buildout

This doesn't seem to work:

```
[buildout]
extends = buildout.cfg
eggs -= python-ldap
eggs += psycopg2
```

The behaviour always seems to be as though the `eggs += psycopg2` line was not present. It doesn't matter which order the two lines are in.

Is this a bug? Is there a way to achieve this result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, `zc.buildout` up to version 1.5.2 doesn't support this use-case. Either the addition *or* the subtraction will succeed.

What happens internally is this:

- For each key, value pair defined in the inheriting section:

  - If the key is using `+=`, take the inherited value, add things, and store it as the new value.
  - If the key is using `-=`, take the inherited value, remove things, and store it as the new value.

After these updates the inherited section is copied, updated with the new values and this is used as the final result.

The ordering is defined by the usual python mapping semantics, thus undefined; either the addition or the subtraction runs last. Because both operations take their input from the inherited section, modify it, then store it as the new value, the operation that runs last overwrites the result of the operation that ran before.

I've [committed a fix for this](http://svn.zope.org/zc.buildout/trunk/?rev=127336&view=rev); I don't have rights to release a new version of `buildout` to pypi though, I'll have to poke those who do.

**Edit**: [`zc.buildout` version 1.6](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/1.6.0#id9) contains this fix.

Comment: Wow. Completely unexpected - but much appreciated. My workaround in the meantime was hardcoding an entire copy of the buildout cfg (minus python-ldap, plus pyscopg2). I'm a little surprised that no one has ever needed to do this before.

Comment: Well, since the fix is contained in [3 lines (not counting comments)](http://svn.zope.org/zc.buildout/trunk/src/zc/buildout/buildout.py?rev=127336&view=diff&r1=127336&r2=127335&p1=zc.buildout/trunk/src/zc/buildout/buildout.py&p2=/zc.buildout/trunk/src/zc/buildout/buildout.py) you could apply it inline in your buildout egg.

Comment: I'd have to do that at deploy time, unfortunately - this is part of a chef deployment, so absolutely everything gets downloaded before running. And if I'm patching buildout at deploy time, I might as well just patch the buildout.cfg itself.

Comment: Fair enough, and quite right. I *think* you can tell buildout to fetch a new version from SVN as a dev egg, but that also has risks with it as far as version control goes.

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to have regressed in [Buildout 2](https://github.com/buildout/buildout/blob/master/src/zc/buildout/buildout.py#L1626). I guess Buildout 2 development had already been branched by the time @MartijnPieters fix got into Buildout 1 and was never merged to the Buildout 2 development branch.